# Open subset in $\Bbb R$ defintion question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Definition:** A set $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ is said to be open if $\forall a \in A, \exists \epsilon >0$ such that $V_\epsilon(a) \subseteq A$.

**Question:** why there is $V_\epsilon(a) \subseteq A$ in definition, not $V_\epsilon(a) \subset A$. I assume that it will be the same because if $V_\epsilon(a) \subseteq A$, then $V_{\epsilon/2}(a) \subset A$. But still interesting, if there are other reasons to use $\subseteq$.

Comment: Because it *can* be equal. That's what happens if, say, $A=(0,2)$, $a=1$ and $\varepsilon=1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos for this case we can use $\epsilon=0.5$ and then $A$ is strict subset (not equal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, the two definitions are equivalent indeed. But the general definition of open subsets via [neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) in an arbitrary [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) $X$ is:

> A set $A \subseteq X$ is said to be open if $\forall a \in A, \exists V\in\mathcal V(a)$ such that $V\subseteq A,$

where $\mathcal V(a)$ denotes the set of all neighborhoods of $a.$

Here, $V\subseteq A$ cannot be replaced by $V\subsetneq A:$ for instance in the [discrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) on $X$, $A:=\{a\}$ is open but contains no other neighborhood of $a$ than $A$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think most people think of $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ as synonyms. Do you think that $\subset$ is "$\subseteq$ and $\neq$" (what I would denote $\subsetneq$)?

If so, any $\subsetneq$-open set is $\subseteq$-open (this is obvious from definition). Now, assume $A$ is $\subseteq$-open. Let $a \in A$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be such that $V_\varepsilon(a) \subseteq A$ (such an $\varepsilon$ exists, by assumption). Then $a \in V_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(a) \subsetneq A$. Therefore $A$ is also $\subsetneq$-open.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you actually already wrote that. Hem, nevermind.

Comment: yes, I always thought that $\subset$ is strict subset. I am going to use $\subsetneq$ since now